# Most efficient way for uploading images (two approaches)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image, performance

**Approach 1**

This approach is the common one. If you are inserting some data containing text
and images, you would upload the images before clicking Save button (saving text) .

**Approach 2**

I created an array of `HttpPostedFile` type:

```
static int i;
static HttpPostedFile[] fp;
```

in .aspx:

```
<ASP:FILEUPLOAD id="btnBrowse" runat="server" />
<br />
<ASP:BUTTON id="btnUpload" runat="server" onclick="addfile_Click"/>
<br />
<ASP:BUTTON id="btnSave" runat="server" onclick="save_Click" />
```

`btnUpload` will add the next image to the array:

```
protected void addfile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (btnBrowse.HasFile)
    {
        fp[i] = btnBrowse.PostedFile;
        i++;
    }
}
```

`btnSave` will insert images in the array:

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    {
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fp[j].FileName);

        var image = SD.Image.FromStream(fp[j].InputStream);

        image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/Profiles_Images/") + filename);
    }
}
```

It works fine. I have two questions:

1. Is the second approach more efficient than the first one?
2. If so, how to save the files in the array without using static (not saving values without static)? Because static is not efficient as you know.

Comment: @HTB: I believe your general statement about static not being efficient is ill-informed; there's nothing to suggest that making something static will make it less efficient than if it wasn't static.  It's all about how much contention for any resource will occur.

Comment: I have read many articles suggesting that using static is a common error between programers !

Comment: @HTB: It isn't.  It's in *how it's used* that is an error.  Just being `static` by itself doesn't make it bad.

Comment: ok correct me . it will make an overload on the page . and does it dispose after the page life cycle ?

Comment: @HTB: Again it's about *how* static is used; I'm challenging the statement that you made that *all* static usage is wrong.  That is an incorrect statement.

Comment: check Alexei Levenkov answer .

Answer (score 0):

Either way is fine, the second option is probably a bit more efficient as it uploads them all at one time rather than posting a file and then posting another.  It will take the same amount of time for the server, but from the user experience, this will be tedious.

However, for a real nice user experience as well as the capability to upload multiple files at once, use uploadify:  http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: There are two reasons for choosing the second one. 1) I have to upload them one by one to enable the user to write a comment . 2) the images will not be saved until the user clicks Save button (this will save other inputs and images together creating a compelete record)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what "efficient" mans for you. Are you concerned about beeing convinient for user (usability?), or what is fastest/most optimal for server (performance?), or correctness (which seem to be the way you've used it in "static is not efficient")...

Using static will not work if you want to support multiple users. Static is rearly reasonable in server side applications and almost never safe to store user's data for server code.

If you want to store files one by one consider using SQL session state or some other persistant storage as files saved in memory between requests could be lost due to process restart.

Comment: yes . it is for multiple users . What else I can use instead of Static ?

Comment: As I've said - consider session state (SQL version if you care about process restarts). There is also nothing particularly wrong about uploading multiple files at once as long as you provide decent UI to enter all necessary data before post.